# What is the best practice for passing props to child component in ReactJs, from the redux store or from parent to child?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my ReactJs application, I have a redux store. In Parent component I am fetching the prop from the redux store. Now, I want to pass this prop to a child component. I have two ways to do this:
1. Send props from parent component to child component.
2. Fetch the prop from the redux store in the child component.

Which way is preferred and why?

Although both will lead to same result. I want to know the difference between the two and which approach is a preferred way.

Comment: You can also use Contex API...

Comment: I prefer to use dumb component that only expect props, and containers that are connected to the store which get the specific props needed by given component. e.g. `User = props => { props.username }`, `UserContainer = connect( /* map state to props */ )(User)`

Comment: Connect your component at the lowest possible level, in this case the child component.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is kind of opinion based, try next rule thumb:

On each step, if your component is not **Readable** or **Hard to Maintain** then you move to the next step.

You start by passing props ***=>*** Using `Context` API ***=>*** State Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The question you're asking is on presentational component VS container component topic.

Containers usually contain business logic, containers are connect to the Redux store as well.

Presenters should only display data from the props you pass in.

There are many benefits that come with such approach. Improved code readability, testability, better separation of concerns and much more.

Continue here - [https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components][1]

Comment: No. Basically I have 2 container components . Now I can pass the prop from parent to child. Or I can fetch the prop from the child container itself from redux store.Want to know which is preferred way?

Comment: Preferred way would be not having 2 container components if you don't need to. If it's done and your child component is already a container, then the whole purpose of this decision is to be able to offload the parent component, meaning you should connect it to the Redux store, no?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I consider that the structure should be consistent with the rest of your repo. If you connected all the smart containers to redux, continue with that line, so it will be clearer for someone else to read your code.